# Unable to find common manager between two nodes

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to find the closest common manager from a tree, given two nodes n1 and n2. This is not a binary tree. I am showing a binary tree for simplicity.

See attached image:

[image]

1. If I pass H & I as two nodes, it should return E
2. If I pass D & I as two nodes, it should return B

Look at the code, everything seems to be working fine except for case where when I pass "I" & "L" as two nodes, **instead of getting E, I am getting "I"** as the manager.

How can I fix it? here is a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qOYsDO

```
class Node
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
        public Node(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            Children = new List<Node>();
        }
    }
class CommonManager
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Node> dictionary;

    public CommonManager()
    {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Node>();
        Node root = new Node("A");
        root.Children.Add(new Node("B"));
        //root.Children.Add(new Node("C"));
        //root.Children.Add(new Node("AA"));
        root.Children[0].Children.Add(new Node("D"));
        root.Children[0].Children.Add(new Node("E"));
        //root.Children[1].Children.Add(new Node("F"));
        //root.Children[1].Children.Add(new Node("G"));
        root.Children[0].Children[1].Children.Add(new Node("H"));
        root.Children[0].Children[1].Children.Add(new Node("I"));
        //root.Children[1].Children[0].Children.Add(new Node("J"));
        //root.Children[1].Children[0].Children.Add(new Node("K"));
        root.Children[0].Children[1].Children[1].Children.Add(new Node("L"));

        Node n1 = root.Children[0].Children[1].Children[1].Children[0];//L
        Node n2 = root.Children[0].Children[1].Children[1];//I

        Node lcm = FindLCM(root, n1, n2);
        if (lcm != null)
            Console.WriteLine("The LCM is " + lcm.Name);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No LCM found.");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }




    static Node FindLCM(Node root, Node n1, Node n2)
    {
        if (root == null)
            return null;

        //If selected node is n1 or n2 return node. 
        if (root == n1 || root == n2)
            return root;

        Node lcm = null;
        int count = 0;
        //Use debug > Windows > Parallel Watch to track variables. 
        foreach (Node child in root.Children)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(child.Name);
            Node temp = FindLCM(child, n1, n2);
            if (temp != null)
            {
                lcm = temp;
                Console.WriteLine("temp.Name:--> " + temp.Name);
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count == 2)
            return root;
        else
            return lcm;
    }

    

}
```

Comment: Can you please define what a "manager node" ist?

Comment: Any node which does not have a child is not a manager node.

Comment: So "I" would be correct, or? At least it does have a child. Why do you expect "E"?

Comment: `A node cannot be its own parent unless its  a root node. `. I am passing two nodes `I` & `L`. in this case `L's`  parent is `I` but when  pass `I`, we cannot return `I` as the parent again. So the next logical choice as per the hierarchy is `E`.  If I pass `D & E`, the parent node would be `B`

Comment: You should probably [edit] your question to make these requirements clear. If you don't want the original nodes as "manager candidates", just use your algorithm starting at the *parents* of the original nodes.